# When i'm trying to run the kafka it shows me the error

Tags: apache-kafka

Zookeeper is running but kafka is giving me an error.
I'm tring to run the cmd as
./bin/windows/kafka-server-start.bat ./config/server.properties

And it gives me the error like

zsh: permission denied: ./bin/windows/kafka-server-start.bat

I'm trying to run the kafka

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to execute the Windows startup script on a Linux machine.

Instead, use the bin/kafka-server-start.sh script and ignore the windows path

Comment: It showing me like this when i try to run your given cmd.
USAGE: bin/kafka-server-start.sh [-daemon] server.properties [--override property=value]*

Comment: You'll still have to provide the properties file as a argument, similar to how you started Zookeeper

Comment: i have not provided anything in zookeeper & its working fine.

Comment: Did you run `bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties`, as the error mentioned?

Comment: Yes but still gives me error .

Comment: Error --->
[2024-03-29 09:23:31,357] ERROR Exiting Kafka due to fatal exception during startup. (kafka.Kafka$)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Socket server failed to bind to 0.0.0.0:9092: Address already in use.
 at kafka.network.Acceptor.openServerSocket(SocketServer.scala:684)
 at kafka.network.Acceptor.<init>(SocketServer.scala:576)
 at kafka.network.DataPlaneAcceptor.<init>(SocketServer.scala:433)
[2024-03-29 09:23:31,358] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)

Comment: That's saying you've either already started kafka, or something else is on port 9092 and you'll have to modify the listeners setting in properties file

Comment: Now how can i resolve it , 
could you please help me in step by step

Comment: You either run `bin/kafka-server-stop.sh` and try again, or you can change the `listeners` line in `server.properties` to use something other than  port 9092

Comment: I'll try and let you know

Comment: Hey thanks for helping me,
Kafka and zookeeper is now working fine.
but when i try to run the kafka-topics.bat
it gives me the error like
zsh: permission denied: bin/windows/kafka-topics.bat

Comment: Again, don't run bat files on Linux environments. Stop entering the windows path for any commands. In fact, I recommend deleting that folder

Comment: Then what can i do if i have the files in kafka folder.
If i will delete that folder then how it works.

Comment: You do not need `bin/windows` . You can delete that or ignore it. Use `bin/kafka-topics.sh` and other **sh** scripts. Not **bat**